# Docker network inside github actions not resolving hosts

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I'm building a ci pipeline to test my nextjs app with prisma/mongodb. To run integration tests I need a mongodb replica set running locally (Non replica set db won't work). To setup the database I'm using docker-compose with 3 db instances and the app within a network. Everything works locally, however, when running in github actions workflow the bootstrapper seems to be unable to resolve database containers hostnames.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo-bootstrapper:
    container_name: mongo-bootstrapper
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./.devcontainer/tests/init-mongo-db/entrypoint.sh:/init.sh
    entrypoint: /init.sh
    networks:
      - mongo-net
  mongo1:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./.devcontainer/tests/replica.key:/opt/replica.key
    command: 
      - --replSet
      - rs0
      - --keyFile
      - /opt/replica.key
      - --port
      - "27017"
    networks:
      - mongo-net
  mongo2:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27027:27027"
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./.devcontainer/tests/replica.key:/opt/replica.key
    command: 
      - --replSet
      - rs0
      - --keyFile
      - /opt/replica.key
      - --port
      - "27027"
    networks:
      - mongo-net
  mongo3:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo3
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27037:27037"
    environment:
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./.devcontainer/tests/replica.key:/opt/replica.key
    command: 
      - --replSet
      - rs0
      - --keyFile
      - /opt/replica.key
      - --port
      - "27037"
    networks:
      - mongo-net
  app:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    env_file: ./.devcontainer/.env.test
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - mongo-net
networks:
  mongo-net:
```

Here's the entrypoint for mongo-bootstrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "########### Waiting for primary ###########"
until mongosh -u root -p root --host mongo1 --eval "printjson(db.runCommand({ serverStatus: 1}).ok)"
  do
    echo "########### Sleeping  ###########"
    sleep 5
  done


echo "########### Waiting for replica 01  ###########"
until mongosh -u root -p root --host mongo2 --port 27027 --eval "printjson(db.runCommand({ serverStatus: 1}).ok)"
  do
    echo "########### Sleeping  ###########"
    sleep 5
  done


echo "########### Waiting for replica 02  ###########"
until mongosh -u root -p root --host mongo3 --port 27037 --eval "printjson(db.runCommand({ serverStatus: 1}).ok)"
  do
    echo "########### Sleeping  ###########"
    sleep 5
  done

echo "########### All replicas are ready!!!  ###########"

echo "########### Initiating replica set ###########"
mongosh -u root -p root --host mongo1 <<EOF
  rs.initiate({
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongo1:27017" },
      { _id: 1, host: "mongo2:27027" },
      { _id: 2, host: "mongo3:27037" }
    ]
  })
EOF

echo "########### Getting replica set status again  ###########"
mongosh --host mongo1 -u root -p root   <<EOF
  rs.status()
EOF

echo "########### Stopping TEMP instance  ###########"
mongod --shutdown
```

This is what gh actions logs when bootstrapping the service:

```
mongo-bootstrapper    | MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo1
mongo-bootstrapper    | ########### Sleeping  ###########
mongo-bootstrapper    | Current Mongosh Log ID: 63fe0727c38672c5fda58e82
mongo-bootstrapper    | Connecting to:      mongodb://<credentials>@mongo1:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.6.2
```

See the github workflow:

```
name: CI & CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
       - dev
       - staging
       - main
jobs:
  cintegration:
   name: Test
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Run tests
        run: ./.devcontainer/tests/runTests.sh
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build the app
        run: npm run build
```

To automate the steps, I have a runTests.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up -d
# Wait for the replica set to be ready
mongo_bootstrapper_running=true
until [ "$mongo_bootstrapper_running" == "false" ]; do
  echo "Waiting for MongoDB replica set to be ready..."
  sleep 5
  mongo_bootstrapper_running=$(docker ps --filter "name=mongo-bootstrapper" -q | wc -l | grep -q "0" && echo false || echo true)
done

# MongoDB replica set is ready, run the tests
echo "MongoDB replica set is ready, run the tests"
# Push database schema
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.test.yml run app npx prisma db push
docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.test.yml run app npm run test:ci
test_exit_code=$?

# Stop the local MongoDB replica set
echo "Stopping the local MongoDB replica set."
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml down

exit $test_exit_code
```

Can someone explain why docker networking isn't working on github actions and is there a way to solve this?